# Is the `ed` editor useful for any purpose besides emergencies and batch editing?

Tags: editors, ed

I'm wondering if the `ed` editor is useful any longer for interactive editing. I know that the `diff` command can produce patches as `ed` scripts and that `ed` is a last resort when the baud rate is super slow. But are there any other reasons to learn and use `ed`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a general purpose editor, probably not, but as a way to get yourself out of a pinch, it's good to know a few basics. The good news is that if you know your way around `vim`, it's likely you can use that knowledge to blunder around in `ed`. The times are changing, but there are still systems that it might be your best editor or connection scenarios that call for it. I've used it from my super-slick smartphone logged into a modern linux box when the connection was bad enough that running a full editor was taking forever and I really needed to just change a line and get out.

Comment: I personally favor `ex` over `ed`; although both are specified by POSIX, `ex` has a *lot* more features, and is actually often the same binary as `vi` (since `vi` is the "visual editor" for `ex`).

Comment: My favorite reason to use ed is because when I'm doing a working session in the terminal I don't like when the full screen editor takes up the full screen, then disappears after I close the editor. With ed, I can keep the context of what I was working on in plain view. To keep track of any changes I made, I simply scroll back; for example, I might grep a file and find where I want to change, edit the file with ed, restart a service, grep logs, edit another file; then think: Oh what happened, so I can scroll back and check the precise changes (all from one terminal)—it's fun!

Answer (score 3):

If you happen to be working on a terminal that doesn't support fancy things like scrollback (for example, an actual teletype), then `ed` really shines.

Answer (score 0):

I've been known to occasionally use `ex` (`vi` in non visual mode, not `ed`) to do small edition when logged remotely through a high latency line (and I put then telnet in line mode). Bigger edition and I'm using `emacs` locally.  The dismiss of telnet in favor of ssh even for inside the intranet remote session has been the raison I stopped doing that.

A long time ago, I've used a line editor on a [this kind of terminals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASR-33_Teletype); it wasn't `ed` nor `ex`.

Answer (score -1):

I've used `ed` to non-interactively rotate my copy of a task list file, supporting #comments.

From `https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic`:

By this time, my copy of the config file has been checked to ensure at least 1 non-#comment, non-blank line exists.

```
function flip () {
    # Return the first non-blank, non #comment line,
    # and move that line (and all preceeding blank and #comment
    # lines) to the end of (our copy of) the config file.
    #
    # ed pattern includes "/", but not "~" or "."
    #Adjust the ed pattern in both places and in countconfiglines
    ed --quiet "$config" <<EndOfEd
/^[A-Za-z0-9\/]/
1,.t$
1,/^[A-Za-z0-9\/]/d
wq
EndOfEd
}
```

Is there a better way?

Also in my professional career as a sysadmin/computer security geek (~50 years), the knowledge of `ed`, an editor that will work over a 110 baud TeleType, as a backup, has been reassuring. My editor choices are :`emacs`,`vim`, `vi`,`nano`, `ed`, `teco`.

Answer (score -2):

[`ed`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_%28text_editor%29) is great for all kinds of editing and fun to use.

`vim` and `emacs` are a little too complicated.

Comment: I guess this is ment as a joke and does not help (-1)

Comment: I'm tempted to call it not an answer, but I'm rolling with "`vim` and `emacs` are a little too complicated" as a reason to use `ed`. Some more information would certainly be useful though